# Unable to Add Default value to a column using INSERT INTO SELECT statement

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

I have the following Schema made in MS Access database.

```
Student1(FirstName, LastName, SchoolName) in database db1
Student2(FirstName, LastName) in database db2 //Note there is no SchoolName column
Student3(FirstName, LastName) in database db3 //Note there is no SchoolName column
```

Now my requirement is to insert the data from both table Student2, Student3 into Student1 table such that Whenever the entry is made from Student2 table  a default value for SchoolName should automatically be added and will be same for all the entries from Student2 table similarly in case of Student3 table.

My resultant table Student1 will have only two school names for all the entries.

```
FirstName   LastName    SchoolName
fn1 ln1 s1
fn2 ln2 s1
fn3 ln3 s1
fn4 ln4 s2
fn5 ln5 s2
```

How should I write query for this

By Using this query I will only be able to insert value for SchoolName in Student1 table. How can I achieve it

INSERT INTO Student1 SELECT FirstName, LastName IN ‘C:\Users\abc\db1’;

Answer (score 0):

Just write two inserts:

```
INSERT INTO Student1 (FirstName, LastName, SchoolName)
    SELECT FirstName, LastName, "s1"
    FROM db2.Student2;

INSERT INTO Student1 (FirstName, LastName, SchoolName)
    SELECT FirstName, LastName, "s2"
    FROM db2.Student3;
```

Although  you could write this in a single statement using `union all`, I don't see any advantage to that.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gordon Linoff I could get the desired output